# Google Apps Script Unexpected Identifier error when using getUnprotectedRanges

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting an Unexpected Identifier error on the 'Logger.log unprotected' line of the below code. I have modified the sample code from the Apps Script documentation so I'm not sure why it's throwing the error.

Code:

```
function UpdateProtection(){
  var sheetName = "AAA";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var protection = sheet.protect();
  var unprotected = getUnprotectedRanges();
  Logger.log unprotected;

}
```

Comment: First what is `getUnprotectedRanges()`?  Did you mean `sheet.getUnprotectedRanges()`?  And second it should be `Logger.log(unprotected);`

Answer (score 0):

Once you call `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` it does not have property call getsheetbyname, so it throw an error.

```
function UpdateProtection(){
  var sheetName = "AAA";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var protection = sheet.protect();
  var unprotected = getUnprotectedRanges();
  Logger.log unprotected;

}
```